# Ef Core 2 set value to ignored property on runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an entity with boolean property named "ReadOnly", the value of this property depends on which user is using the application.

In the DbContext i configured the property to be ignored.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Ignore(e => e.ReadOnly);
    }
}
```

How can i set the correct value calculated on runtime so that i haven't to remind to calculate the property everytime?

EDIT: I was thinking something like

```
int loggedUserId = HttpSession.UserId;
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(e => e.ReadOnly).Value = loggedUserId > 5;
```

This way i have always the correct value based on User logged to the application.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Can you elaborate more on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: You would have to set the property on each request coming in.

Comment: My application is a micro service and MyDbContext is created on each request so i can set property on each request but i can't figure out how to do

Comment: Onmodelcreating doesnt happen per request

Comment: You are right, i mean that loggedUserId can be retrive on each request like for multi tenant global filter.http://gunnarpeipman.com/net/ef-core-global-query-filters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that AutoMapper has ProjectTo function that does what i need, ProjectTo will tell AutoMapper’s mapping engine to emit a select clause to the IQueryable

Example of my configuration:

```
 configuration.CreateMap(typeof(Entity), typeof(Entity))
    .ForMember(nameof(Entity.IsReadOnly), opt.MapFrom(src => currentUserResolver.GetUserId() > 5));
```

Usage:

```
myDbSet.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<TEntity>();
```

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters), but I'm not sure it will work since you need to set the property per request. Your best bet is just to make a method on the class that accepts the user and returns the calculated value. Something like this:

```
bool IsReadOnly(int userId){
return userId > 5;
}
```

Comment: I use filters but a filter is a boolean condition that filter results, i can't set value to properties